# Group consecutive sequences of items in array that contains "separator" items

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array, coming from a loop data like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24 September 2013
    [1] => .................
    [2] => .................
    [3] => .................
    [4] => .................
    [5] => 25 September 2013
    [6] => .................
    [7] => .................
    [8] => 27 September 2013
    [9] => .................
    [10] => .................
    [11] => .................
    [12] => .................
    [13] => 28 September 2013
    [14] => .................
    [15] => .................
)
```

How can this array be converted into a two dimensional Separated by Date like:

```
Array
(
   [24 September 2013] => Array
       (
        [0] => .................
        [1] => .................
        [2] => .................
        [3] => .................
       )
   [25 September 2013] => Array
        (
        [0] => .................
        [1] => .................
        )
   [27 September 2013] => Array
        (
        [0] => .................
        [1] => .................
        [2] => .................
        [3] => .................
        )
   [28 September 2013] => Array
       (
        [0] => .................
        [1] => .................
       )
)
```

I am using foreach loop to generate abbove single dimensional array using 2 values

```
$array = Array();
foreach($results as $value) {
    $array[] = $value->date;
    $array[] = $value->text;
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't seem to belong to the output of your first array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. It uses the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to identify values representing a date.

```
$transformed = array();

$key = null;
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($key === null || strtotime($value) !== false) {
        // create new key and initialise to array
        $transformed[$value] = array();
        $key = $value;
    }
    else {
        // append $value to existing $key array
        $transformed[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the idea. But we don't know what are those `.....` values, maybe some of them are also somekind of datetime standard format that strtotime will recognize...

Answer (score 0):

You need to recognize the date somehow. If it is directly in format as you shown you can use regex

```
$array = Array();
$curArray = null;
$date = null;
foreach($results as $value) {
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,2} [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}$/'), $value->date) === 1){
        if($curArray !== null)
            $array[$date] = $curArray;

        $date = $value->date;
    }
    else{
        $curArray[] = $value->text;
    }
}
```